# Bounded and surjective map from counting $L^1$ to separable Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

> Let $\mathscr{X}$ be a separable Banach space and let $\mu$ be counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $\{x_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is a countable dense subset of the unit ball of $\mathscr{X}$, and define $T:L^{1}(\mu)\rightarrow \mathscr{X}$ by $Tf = \sum_{1}^{\infty}f(n)x_n$.
>
> a.) $T$ is bounded.
>
> b.) $T$ is surjective.

Attempted proof a.) We have that $Tf = \sum_{1}^{\infty}f(n)x_n$, hence (from Henry) $$\lVert Tf\rVert  = \lVert \sum_{1}^{\infty}f(n)x_n\rVert \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}|f(n)|\lVert x_n\rVert \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}|f(n)| = \lVert f\rVert_{1}$$
I am not sure where the last part comes from I thought $\lVert f\rVert_{1} = \int |f|d\mu$.

Attempted proof b.) I need to show that if for all $y\in \mathscr{X}$ there exists an $x\in L^{1}(\mu)$ such that $T(x) = y$.

So, suppose $y\in\mathscr{X}$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$. Let $T_n\rightarrow T$ such that $$\lVert T_n x_n - Tx\rVert \rightarrow 0 \ \text{as} \ n\rightarrow \infty$$

Can I suppose now that there is a unique $y$ somewhere after this to show that that $T$ is surjective?

Comment: Seems like you have read through 4 chapters of Folland within 5 months. That's fast.

Comment: well my first semester we did chapter 1 and 2 and I got an A in the class. Now this semester we do chapters 3,5, and 6. I did not have much problems with chapter 3 more or less and as we got into 5 it started to get more and more confusing for me

Comment: @HenryW. Should I just delete this post?

Comment: Just add some of your thoughts. btw Boundedness follows easily: $$  \lVert Tf \rVert = \lVert \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)x_n \rVert \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(n)| \lVert x_n \rVert \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(n)| = \lVert f \rVert_1
$$

Comment: @HenryW. I thought $\lVert f\rVert_{1} = \int |f| d\mu$?

Comment: It is given that $\mu$ is the counting measure, so integration can be converted to a infinite sum.

Comment: That is,$\mu (\{n\})=1$ so $\int |f|\;d\mu=\sum_n|f(n)|.$

Comment: Do you know where this is in the book?

Comment: @MorganWeiss Use the Monotone Convergence Theorem on the partial sums. It is not explicitly stated in the book, but there are some exercises that use it. (Exercise 2.22 for example)

Comment: The image of $T$ is closed and it contains the subspace generated by $\{x_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$. So  $T$ is surjective.

Comment: Why is the image closed?

Comment: @HenryW. could you help me with proving $T$ is surjective?

Comment: @Wolfgang If you're still looking for it, Folland talks about the $\ell^2(A)$ norm near the top of page 173, in the Hilbert spaces section.  It's not too bad to generalize to $\ell^p(A)$, in this case $p=1$, especially now we're more familiar with how $L^P$ works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof that $T$ is surjective.

(0) Obviously the $0$ vector of $X$ is in the image of $T.$

(1) For $x\in X$ and $\|x\|\ne 0,$  let $x'=x/\|x\| .$

(2) Let $j(1)$ be the least $j$ such that $0<\|x_j-x'\|<1/2.$ Let $f(j(1))=1.$

$$\text {(3)......................Let }\quad z_n=x'-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{j(i)}f(j(i)).$$ We have $0<\|z_1\|<1/2.$ Suppose  $0<\|z_n\|<2^{-n}.$  Let $j(n+1)$ be the least $j>j(n)$ such that $$0<\|x_j-(z_n/\|z_n\|)\|<1/2.$$( This is possible because $\{x_j\}_{j\in N}\backslash S$ is dense in the closed unit ball for any finite set $S.$)

Let $f(j(n+1))=\|z_{n+1}\|.$

(4) We have $$z_{n+1}    =z_n-x_{j(n+1)}f(j(n+1))=z_n-x_{j(n+1)}\|z_n\|=$$ $$=\|z_n\| \cdot \|(z_n/\|z_n\|)-x_{j(n+1)}\|.$$ $$\text {So }\quad 0<\|z_n\|<2^{-n}\implies 0<\|z_{n+1}\|<2^{-(n+1)}.$$

(5) Finally let $g(m)=0$ for $m\not \in \{j(n):n\in N\}$ and $g(j(n))=\|x\|f(j(n)).$ We  have $$\sum_{m\in N} | g(m)|=\sum _{n \in N}\|x\|f(j(n))\leq \sum_{n\in N} \|x\|2^{-n}=2\|x\|.$$ If $m'$ is the largest $j(i)$ not exceeding $m,$ then $m'\to \infty$ as $m\to \infty$ (because $j(n+1)>j(n)$),and for $m\geq j(1)$ we have $$\|x-\sum_{i\leq m} x_ig(i)\|=\|z_{m'}\|<2^{-m'}.$$ So $x=T(g).$

Comment: The space $L^1(N)$ with the counting measure on $N$ is usually called $l_1$ or $l^1$,

Comment: The idea is that if $z_n$, as defined in (3), is small but not $0$, we find  some $x_j$ close to $z_n/\|z_n\|$ and scale it down  by the factor $\|z_n\|$ so that $z_{n+1}=z_n-x_j \|z_n\|$ is smaller..

Comment: Thanks but your proof goes way over my head